# Specify options for the jvm launched by pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, jvm-arguments, pyspark

How /where are the jvm options used by the pyspark script when launching the jvm it connects to specified?

I am specifically interested in specifying jvm debugging options e.g.

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pyspark` uses the `bin/spark-class` script to start the client that you see running in your terminal / console. You can just append whatever options necessary to `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx=2g -Xms=1g -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y..."
```